# How do I make a JSONP request with the Twitter 1.1 api?

Tags: javascript, twitter, jsonp

In Head First HTML5 the authors make a `jsonp` request and specify a callback by inserting the following element into their html file:

```
<script src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/wickedsmartly.json?callback=updateTweets">
```

How do I do the same thing with the Twitter 1.1 API?

I've created a developer account and registered an application and I've tried using the following url src in a script element:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/wickedsmartly.json?q=%23freebandnames&since_id=24012619984051000&max_id=250126199840518145&result_type=mixed&count=4&callback=updateTweets
```

Which I made by using the url that was given to me by Twitter's OAuth tool. I'm not sure how to construct the url using the all the different access numbers or token numbers that twitter is giving me. I'm also not sure if it's possible to use the `jsonp` technique anymore with twitter's API.

If it's possible, how do I do it?